# Upload video to Facebook App page?

Tags: video, upload, facebook

When you create a Facebook Connect app/site you automatically get a Facebook app page on Facebook. This page has a log and now I'm wondering if it's possible for users of the app to upload videos to this app log? If so, I want to use these videos on  my Facebook Connect page. Or is there a better way to collect videos from the users of the Facebook Connect app?

I want people to be able to record and upload their videos directly on Facebook using the Facebook interface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late possibly but there is a blog post mentioning how to upload videos to applications and/or pages. This is something I'm looking at doing at the moment, I haven't tried it out yet, but if I find anything more I'll post the results here.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/

Comment: broken link! i guess it's not possible anymore :(

Comment: Facebook broke their links. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an app, Facebook doesn't create a page for it anymore.